# simple user-feedback collection service

Tags: windows, service, user-feedback

**Short:** I am looking for a very simple (configuration/maintenance wise) solution, that would allow to collect user-feedback/bug-reports from my apps/web-sites over the internet.

**Long:**
Right now I have very simple web-app written using ASP.NET MVC that receives http-post requests at `http://localhost/feedback` and saves them as `c:\temp\{guid}-feedback.txt`. I used [UltiDev HttpVpn](http://ultidev.com/products/index.htm) (BTW it's very cool) to expose this page to the internet without having to put my app in DMZ. I collect following information (through a feedback form in the app, or a web-site's feedback page): user name, e-mail, type of the message (feature request, bug report, comment), application name (hard-coded in the app that sends the feedback), and message-text/comment.

**About E-mail:**
E-mail is not good enough, since there will be no e-mail client on most of the computers my apps are running at (also, it takes too many clicks to send an e-mail).

**About JIRA:**
IMHO JIRA is too heavy for what I need. I might be wrong, since I have never installed/configured it myself. Does it have a http-post interface (so I can put my own interface on)?

.NET on Windows solution preferred
**FREE** is a requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worth checking out FogBugz. I used it many versions ago and it has changed a lot since then.

But it allows you to report app crashes / bugs, etc. through a number of mechanisms (see link for details): http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBUGZ/LearnMore.html?section=NewPlatform#hist_PullCases

Comment: Forgot to mention that it has to be free.

Answer (score 1):

To my opinion http://www.useresponse.com is a nice alternative to SaaS services (will be once released on December 2011) you can install on your site and customize up to your satisfaction (both look and functionality).

Commercial, though. Don't think you'll have enough functionality from free scripts (neither support and new features).