# User feedback collection API service

Tags: android, mobile, user-feedback

*Tagged with `[android]` so that someone will actually read this, but applies equally to other application platforms.*

We have a number of Android and iPhone applications which have user-feedback functionality incorporated into their user interfaces. These allow the user to leave comments, report bugs, rate the application, request support, etc.

Currently, the applications make a web service call to our backend, which converts them into email and sends them to us.

We would like to replace this with an API call to a remote backend service hosted by someone else, a service that specialises in this sort of thing, and provides us with a web interface for viewing and collating the feedback.  The API would need to support arbitrary fields that we can set up as we see fit.

I was hoping to somehow integrate this with the Google Analytics APIs for Android and iPhone, but it's not flexible enough. The likes of FogBugz would seem to do the job, but it's too heavyweight a solution - we don't need anything that fancy.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764739/simple-user-feedback-collection-service) touches on the same issue, but concentrates on self-hosted software. I'm looking for a service provided by someone else.

Free services preferred, for obvious reasons, but commercial options considered also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've heard good things about GetSatisfaction http://getsatisfaction.com/
UserVoice as well http://uservoice.com/

Comment: Yeah, that looks nice. The API is also expensive for what it is ($289 per month).

Comment: Google Moderator is free but it might not have all the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: Here's a site with some aggregated information on this topic. Again most are pay-for-services, but they do offer free basic packages: http://webification.com/top-10-best-customer-feedback-tools

Answer (score 4):

You can look into [userrules.com](http://www.userrules.com/pricing). We expose an API to collect feedback which is available with all plans. Also with single plan you can configure your all applications as separate products. Lots of iphone apps are using our API to collect the feedback and then our Admin to manage those.

Comment: This seems extremely on-topic and unworthy of spam/down-votes. @Pavitar clearly indicates his affiliation with the company in accordance with SO policy.

Answer (score 1):

[www.SimpleFeedback.com](http://www.simplefeedback.com) offers a feedback service that has a web service API for you to submit your feedback. You'll have to map your fields to our defined fields.  Along with basic fields like name, email, rating, and comment, we have two custom fields called feedback type and feedback category.  You get to define the types and categories.  For example, you can define the types to be "Bug Report", "Suggestion", "Question", or "Testimonial".  Categories are subtypes.  Each Type has its own set of Categories.

We can notify you via email when feedback is submitted.  Our SimpleFeedback Center stores all your feedback and provides a nice UI for reporting, sorting, filtering, responding, and other feedback management tools.

We also provide a feedback button and feedback form to use on websites who do not have their own form. We have a plugin for self hosted WordPress blogs, too. An iPhone feedback form is also available for developers who don't want to write their own.

Answer (score 0):

[HelpStack](https://github.com/happyfoxinc/helpstack-android) has both free and paid solutions. In free solution you will have to communicate via Email. For paid solution, you will have to go with [ZenDesk](https://www.zendesk.com/), [HappyFox](https://www.happyfox.com/) or [Desk.com](http://www.desk.com/). It supports both iOS and Android. I haven't tried it yet, but it looks promising. It also has a FAQ section support.

**Edit :** I just tried the free solution. It simply opens an email app, nothing else. It does have a FAQ section, but no chat support.

Comment: I can't get even the free version to work.  It gets stuck on `getActivity()` when I put `HSHelpStack.getInstance(getActivity()).showHelp(getActivity());` in the onClick method of an onClickListener.  Any ideas?