# Sending email in Android with developer's email , where password in plaintext - is this OK?

Tags: android, email, plaintext

According to my requirements, I need to make a form with to take feedback in my android app. While I was searching how to send email, I found this question

[Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)

It has a lot of votes, but it has specific feature: password, which is used to be send email, literally hardcoded (as plaintext). Someone left comment about possibility to decompile apk file, but nobody cares.I can't leave credentials to gmail-account in my app.

Is there any other approach to send email without making your account credentials available after decompile?

Comment: "Are any other approach to send email" -- ask your Web server to send the email on your behalf.

Comment: Yes, obvious reply. But it means the having a bit more in backend.

Comment: Consider the legal and other implications if phishing or scam emails were sent from the account your app uses.

Comment: If the email will come from the user to you i think the best way is let the user decide from where he will send the email, that way he also choose how you will reply he. I think you should send an Intent and let the user handle that. But if you wanna some security, but not 100%, you can store an encrypted password, and use some logic to decrypt , but if someone break your code, will see that logic. If you really need to send that mail from a unique address, the best way is send a request to server and let they send.

Comment: Unless you want it to be insecure, there are only two ways: a) send via intent, or b) send via server. period.

Comment: "is this ok?" of course not. anything in the android app, not matter how it is written, is to be considered public.

Comment: alternatives: google + "android user feedback api" plenty of ready-made services for that, if you don't want to write your own. e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923942/user-feedback-collection-api-service